# Python Kivy - pos_hint not updating in FloatLayout using code

Tags: python, kivy

I've been trying to adjust the position of this Label, but everytime I've adjusted the pos_hint it keeps the label in the middle of the window. I've searched a lot, but all of the results use the .kv file which I'm trying to avoid. I looked at the documentation on https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.floatlayout.html and it appears that I'm using it correctly, but can't figure this out to save my life. After printing out the pos_hint it appears that the variable is adjusting, just not adjusting on the screen.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.7')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):    
        f = FloatLayout()
        lab = Label(text="text", pos_hint={"x": 0, 'top':1})
        f.add_widget(lab)
        return f

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = TestApp();
    test.run()
```

Comment: You need a `size_hint` along with a `pos_hint`. Something like `size_hint=(.2,.4)`. I highly recommend learning how to use the kv file. I was against it at first too, but it truly isn't too tough to learn and works much better than trying to do everything in plain python!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't give constraints to your `Label` widget's size (height & width), it'll will try to become as big as its parent widget (in the case of using `FloatLayout` widget). You can try to set `size_hint` property of your `Label` widget and/or set the `height` and `width` property of your `Label` widget.

```
...
lab = Label(text="text", pos_hint={"x": 0, 'top':1})
lab.size_hint= (None, None)
lab.width= 100 # Label widget's width
lab.height = 56 # Label widget's height
f.add_widget(lab)
...
```